# Django Rest Framework - Envelope for response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm wanting to convert an API from flask to Django Rest Framework.  Currently, the requirements are that the responses are put inside of a basic json structure.

eg.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {actual results here}
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

A generic approach would be to inherit from the DRF's JSONRenderer and adapt it to your needs, see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/.

Aditionally you propably want to adapt the pagination style to your old flask api, see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom response:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomSuccessResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        result = {
            'status': 'success',
            'data': data,
        }
        super(CustomSuccessResponse, self).__init__(data=result)
```

And then in your view you can use it like this:

```
 return CustomSuccessResponse(data={'message': 'actual results'})
```